# No qt_build in ROS Jade?

Tags: ros-jade, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

will there be a version of qt_build in Jade? Or how do I replace it?

Greetings,
Stephan

**Edit**

Thanks for the solutions. I actually didn't made it work with Qt5, because of some changes in namespaces between Qt4 and Qt5. So my solution is based on [CMake's Documentation about Qt4](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindQt4.html). This is probably quite similar to you answer, so I marked it as a solution.

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213182/no-qt_build-in-ros-jade?/) by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you use CMake 2.8.11 or newer (allowed in Jade and I think also Indigo) it gets even easier:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(testproject)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Tell CMake to create the helloworld executable
add_executable(helloworld WIN32 main.cpp)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5.
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets)
```

if you replace every 5 by a 4 you will get it build against qt4. Mixing is not allowed for the same target but inside the same CMakeLists.txt is ok

---

Originally posted by [Simon Schmeisser](https://answers.ros.org/users/21773/simon-schmeisser/) with karma: 229 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2